# How do I use raw sockets in Perl?

Tags: perl, networking, sockets

How can you get a **raw** socket in Perl, and then what's the best way to built a packet for use with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Net::RawIP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-RawIP) was what I was looking for:

```
use Net::RawIP;
$a = new Net::RawIP;
$a->set({ip => {saddr => 'my.target.lan',daddr => 'my.target.lan'},
         tcp => {source => 139,dest => 139,psh => 1, syn => 1}});
$a->send;

$a->ethnew("eth0");
$a->ethset(source => 'my.target.lan',dest =>'my.target.lan');      
$a->ethsend;

$p = $a->pcapinit("eth0","dst port 21",1500,30);
$f = dump_open($p,"/my/home/log");
loop $p,10,\&dump,$f;
```

Comment: Why was this the answer to your question rather than the built-in socket operations? Do you have to choose a particular NIC or something?

Comment: I was looking for example code -- like, "here's how you set the source IP. Here's how you set specific TCP flags." None of the other posts answered that.. they basically said, "RTFM"

Answer (score 7):

The same way you do in C... by setting the socket type when creating the socket.

In the example on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/ext/Socket/Socket.pm) use **SOCK_RAW** rather than **SOCK_DGRAM** (UDP) or **SOCK_STREAM** (TCP).

NOTE: creating raw sockets typically requires administrative privileges (i.e. root on UNIX). Windows OS's may have disabled ability to create raw sockets, you'll just have to test it and see.

Comment: The page you linked doesn't mention raw sockets.

Comment: Try reading your man pages. The Socket module works as a thin layer over BSD sockets, what you read about them is also applicable on Perl sockets.

Comment: Leon is correct, the information you want is in the man page for socket() - e.g. "man socket" on any *nix should give you what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps searching [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) might help?  [IO::Socket](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO) comes to mind.

Comment: That explains regular sockets, but how do I build a *raw* socket and set its parameters?

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you should be able to do it using the socktype and protocol arguments to the IO::Socket constructor.

Comment: If I knew what I were doing, I wouldn't be here. :)

Answer (score 5):

At first I was thinking that most previous answers were not responsive to the question.
After further thought, I think the author is probably not asking the right question.

If you're writing an application, you don't usually think of "building packets". you just open sockets, format up the data payload, and it's the protocol stack that builds packets with your data.  OK, if you're using datagrams, you do need to define, generate and parse your payloads.  But you typically let the kernel encapsulate it at the network level (e.g. add IP header) or link layer (e.g. add Ethernet framing).  You usually don't use pcap.  Sometimes just pack and unpack and maybe vec is enough.

If you're writing an unusual packet processor such as an active hostile attack tool, a man-in-the-middle process, or a traffic shaping device, then would be more likely to be "building packets" and using pcap.  Maybe Net::Packet is for you also.

Comment: Right on. What question *should* I be asking?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do, not how you are trying to do it :)

Answer (score 4):

As austirg and others said, Socket will do this just fine:

```
use Socket;

socket my $socket, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0 or die "Couldn't create raw socket: $!";

send $socket, $message, $flags, $to or die "Couldn't send packet: $!";

my $from = recv $socket, $message, $length, $flags or die "Couldn't receive from socket: $!";
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic call to get a socket is...  socket().  It comes standard with perl 5.  perl 5 basically gives you the standard socket(), bind(), listen(), accept() calls that traditional UNIX does.

For a more object oriented model, check out IO::Socket.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you're trying to use raw sockets to send a pile of SYN packets, and you just "use Socket;" that's going to fill up your ARP tables and bomb out with "No buffer space available" and a stack of "CLOSE_WAIT" entries in "netstat" (which stops your machine doing any more connections of any kind until some of them free up).

Or in other words - you do really need Net::RawIP - it makes a difference.